# How to control dmx via usb using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, serial-port, usb, dmx512

I am looking for a way to sent dmx data from nodejs (or other) via USB. This is a USB-DMX512 product that I want to use: https://www.conrad.nl/p/eurolite-usb-dmx512-dmx-interface-1529978

Can anybody point me in the right direction on how to do this? 
All tips are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: By chance, I watch a guy on YouTube that works for Monzo. Remembered he had a video about DMX, also writes NodeJS. I've never done anything like this but it seems like he's worked out all of the caveats with the protocol. Give it a watch and tell me what you think. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rJIqyxE3aY - On a side note, just checked your profile and I love your work.

Comment: Hi Razki, thanks a lot for that. I have watched it, but it contains some new stuff for me, that I guess I have to dig into. Will let you know how it goes.